# Return list of values c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new in Asp and I develop all querys with stored procedures:

I have a **method** like this:

```
  Filler.Fill(new PeriodoLogic().lstConsultaParcial(tabla).ConvertAll(o => (object)o), ref this.radcmbPeriodo, "nPeriodo", "nPeriodo", true);
```

**lstConsultaParcial Method:**

```
 public List<object> lstConsultaParcial(object Entidad)
        {
            return new PeriodoData().lstConsultaParcial(Entidad);
        }
```

**View:**

```
<td><telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="radcmbPeriodo" Width="200px" MarkFirstMatch="true" Filter="Contains" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled"                    
                    EmptyMessage="Seleccionar" ></telerik:RadComboBox></td>    
                     <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<b class='red'>Requerido</b>" ControlToValidate="radcmbPeriodo"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
```

It fills radcombobox, consulting a simple stored procedure, it receive values, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 as:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYOkM.png)

as you can see it returns values 1 to 12, so I think I dont need consult stored procedure, how can I send simple a list of 1 to 12 instead call stored procedure?

Comment: what if the values change in the database that your procedure uses? You will have the wrong data displaying then,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is simple. You don't want to call that function which goes to call the SP.

Using LINQ below, you can quickly generate a list of numbers from 1 to 12.

```
List<int> myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
return myList;
```

This is what you need to return from the method that your `Kendo` control calls.

Comment: But what code I need to change to return that list?

Comment: I try it as `List<int> myList = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
           
            return new PeriodoData().lstConsultaParcial(myList);`, but it don't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate it like this:

```
var nums = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).ToList();
```

Comment: You can remove `.Select(x => x)`